# Enforce that static and class methods can only be called through instance and not through class

Tags: python, class, properties, static-methods, class-method

Professor gave us the following code:

```
class Dolar:

    @staticmethod
    def dolar():
        return 4680
    
    def __init__(self,pesos):
        self.pesos = pesos

    def convertir(self):
        return self.pesos * Dolar.dolar()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':

    print(Dolar.dolar())
    valor_actual = Dolar(5000)
    print(valor_actual.dolar())
    print(f'{valor_actual.convertir():,}')
```

Which prints the value for the method "dolar" through both instance and class. Now he wants us to prevent calling said method through the class so that it can only be done through instance.

We recently learned about @property in python so it may be related.

Edit: I am not completely sure what the proffesor wants to happen when calling Dolar.dolar vs valor_actual.dolar because he was purposefully ambiguous but I'm assuming he meant calling Dolar.dolar should give out an error while valor_actual.dolar should give the actual value.

Comment: This is the default behavior. Just remove `staticmethod`?

Comment: Nah, I though that but he said it has to remain a 'staticmethod' after doing that. There's another example where this has to be done to both class and static methods, so that the "values" remain or can be modified for the whole class while only accesing them through instances.

Comment: Can you please explain it more clearly in terms of Python code, so in the revised code with what your professor wants, what is supposed to happen when doing `Dolar.dolar()` vs `valor_actual.dolar()`?  Include this update in the question please.

Answer (score 2):

This is some sort of trick question it looks like. Your professor is asking you to contradict the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod) of what this decorator does:

> A static method can be called either on the class (such as C.f()) or on an instance (such as C().f()). Moreover, they can be called as regular functions (such as f()).

It's unclear exactly what is wanted. However, one way to get around this requirement would be to define the method as part of the class constructor. This way the function does not exist on class itself, and therefore cannot be called.

```
def bar():
    return 1

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = staticmethod(bar)
```

```
>>> Foo().bar()
1
>>> Foo.bar()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ...
    Foo.bar()
    ^^^^^^^
AttributeError: type object 'Foo' has no attribute 'bar'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can implement your own [static method descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#static-methods) by overriding the `__get__` method with a check that the applicable object is `None`, in which case the method is called via the class:

```
class StaticMethod:
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        if not obj:
            raise NotImplementedError('Must be called via an instance.')
        return self.f

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.f(*args, **kwargs)

class Dolar:
    @StaticMethod
    def dolar():
        return 4680
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/VengefulThoughtfulSyndrome

Comment: Could these conditions: if not obj:
            raise notimplementederror('must be called via an instance.')
        return self.f
Be set directly in the static method instead of in the descriptor?

Comment: Unfortunately the object that invokes the descriptor is not accessible to the static method being called. You can use unreliable methods such as inspecting the code in the caller's frame to try to figure out if the invoking object is a class or an instance but such static analysis would be far from fool-proof.